# Calculate interest rate APR (compound and normal) on a daily basis

Tags: united-kingdom, interest-rate, compound-interest

Let's assume there is an interest rate of 0.61%. So, the interest is 0.61% AER which is then divided by 365 and paid daily. The interest rate is for the year, not per day however interest is paid daily.

A calculation found online is shown below:

[image]

I am putting an amount of 20000 as an example. Based on the image above I should get the following:

```
[20000*(1+0.00001671232)^30]−20000
```

which means the interest is nearly `10 pounds` for **30** days? And `122 pounds` for **365** days?

A calculator for a normal interest [online](https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/financial/simple-interest-plus-principal-calculator.php) for a year also gave me this:
[image]

In either case, the interest seems a bit unreal for a fcsc bank. Is there a chance that I will get taxed on any amount?

Comment: In what way does "the interest seems a bit unreal for a fcsc bank"?

Answer (score 1):

If you put 20,000 into a bank and they pay 0.61% over a year then that will mean

20,000 * 0.0061 = 122  of interest

The compounding will raise that number slightly.

> In either case, the interest seems a bit unreal for a fcsc bank. Is
> there a chance that I will get taxed on any amount?

0.61% seems good today, but a few decades ago you could get 10 times that much.

The question about is it taxable, depends on the jurisdiction and what other income you have.

Comment: Lloyds and highstreet banks give around 0.01% lately. 0.62% was a shock for me. I wonder if I can find an even better one

Comment: @Datacrawler Depending on what kind of saving rules you are willing to play with (e.g. flexible, fixed-term, with X month of notice), there are quite a few options in the UK (or England, at least) that is paying better than 0.62% as of Mar 2022. Comparison websites for "UK saving accounts" (of which there are many) are your friend in this case.

Comment: Can confirm you can get upward of 2%+ on normal savings account without any fixed term.

Answer (score 0):

You *may* have to pay tax on interest from savings. It depends upon how much you earn and what income tax bracket you're in.

[This page](https://www.gov.uk/apply-tax-free-interest-on-savings) has the full, official detail.